How to provide a custom HttpClient for a per-host FlurlClient
If I'm using the short-form fluent APIs of flurl ("some-url/whatever".GetAsync()), how do I explicitly configure the HttpClient per-host?
I've looked at the documentation, but ConfigureClientForUrl doesn't give me anywhere to replace the HttpClient that flurl will use with my own instance.

Here's how you would configure the HttpClient:
FlurlHttp.ConfigureClientForUrl("https://some-api.com")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient => ...);

Replacing the client entirely isn't supported with the clientless pattern.
